# How do I create a loop that parses all of the messages from discord conversations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, discord.py

I am creating a discord script for deleting messages, but in my older version, I couldn't delete messages those were not in the first hundred, because you are not allowed to parse more than 100 messages at a time.

URL for getting discord messages is like this:

```
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/***<USER ID>***/messages?limit=100
```

After the first request, you must get all the older messages using the ID of the latest message from the previous request.

```
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/***<USER ID>***/messages?before=<***LAST MESSAGE ID***>&limit=100
```

Though, I can not figure out an algorithm for a loop that will go through the conversation and stop whenever it reaches the end.

Comment: You will need to use a [recursive function.](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/)

Comment: Yep, for hours trying to figure out how would it work.

Comment: Yeah, I've only written one (for an actual program to use) before and it does take a bit of thinking to understand how it works but this is definitely the way to go about your problem. Often, if you need to iterate over something but don't know how many iterations you will do, a recursive function will normally do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The Discord API docs for [`GET /channels/{channel.id}/messages`](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages) states the following (emphasis mine):

> Returns the messages for a channel. If operating on a guild channel,
>   this endpoint requires the `VIEW_CHANNEL` permission to be present on
>   the current user. If the current user is missing the
>   'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY' permission in the channel then this will return
>   no messages (since they cannot read the message history). **Returns an
>   array of message objects on success.**

This means that you can loop over the API endpoint using `limit=100` until an array is returned that does not have 100 message objects.

Example code below. Note that this does not handle authorization.

```
import requests

messages = requests.get('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/<CHANNEL ID>/messages?limit=100')
last_message_id = messages[-1].id

while len(messages) < 100:
    messages = requests.get('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/<CHANNEL ID>/messagesmessages?before={0}&limit=100'.format(last_message_id)
    last_message_id = messages[-1].id
```

---

As an aside, with `discord.py` you can use [`channel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge) to delete messages from a channel.

Comment: I'm not. I'm using the requests module and prefer it that way. Discord.py does not solve the problem.

Comment: I suggest you remove the `discord.py` tag if your question is not related to the library. Answer edited to use the API directly